# Shiny submitButton not updating my result

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny to make my Rcode interactive. At the first run, I got an initial result [My initial Shiny output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf18i.png). The problem I have is that submitButton which should update my result after changing the input is not working. I have searched stackoverflow and could not find a solution. I will be glad if you can help.

My ui.R code is:

```
      library(shiny)
      source("travelcbr1.R")

      shinyUI(fluidPage(

        # Application title.
        titlePanel("TRAVEL RECOMMENDATION"),


        sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("HolidayType", "Choose an holiday type:", 
                        choices = c("Bathing", "Active", "Education", "Recreation", "Wandering", "Language", "Skiing", "City")),

            selectInput("Transportation", "Choose a means of Transportation:", 
                        choices = c("Plane", "Train", "Coach", "Car")),

            selectInput("Accomodation", "Choose an Accomodation:", 
                        choices = c("One Star", "Two Stars", "Three Stars", "Four Stars", "Five Stars", "Holiday Flat")),

            selectInput("Duration", "Duration (days):", 
                        choices = c("less than 4", "4 - 6", "7 - 9", "10 - 12", "13 - 15", "16 - 20", "more than 20" )),

            numericInput("Price", "Price:", 500),
            # selectInput("Price", "Price ($):",
            #             choices = c("less than 500", "500 - 1000", "1000 - 1500", "1500 - 2000", "2000 - 2500", "2500 - 3000", "3500 - 4000", "4000 - 4500", "500+" )),

            selectInput("Season", "Season:", 
                        choices = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")),

            selectInput("NumberOfPersons", "Number Of Persons:", choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12 and above")),

            helpText("Click submit button to view your six best destinations"),

            submitButton("Update")
          ),


          mainPanel(

              tableOutput("view")
              # dataTableOutput("view")
          )
        )
      ))
```

My server.R code is this:

```
    library(shiny)

    source("travelcbr1.R")

    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        output$view <- renderTable({

          Accomodation <- reactive({switch(input$Accomodation, 
                                           "Holiday Flat" = 6,
                                           "Five Stars" = 5,
                                           "Four Stars" = 4,
                                           "Three Stars" = 3,
                                           "Two Stars" = 2,
                                           "One Star" = 1)})

          Price <- reactive({input$Price})


          Transportation <- reactive({switch(input$Transportation, 
                                             "Plane" = 4,
                                             "Train" = 3,
                                             "Coach" = 2,
                                             "Car" = 1)})

          HolidayType <- reactive({switch(input$HolidayType, 
                                          "Active" = 8,
                                          "Skiing" = 7,
                                          "Bathing" = 6,
                                          "Wandering" = 5,
                                          "Recreation" = 4,
                                          "City" = 3,
                                          "Language"= 2,
                                          "Education" = 1)})

          Season <- reactive({switch(input$Season, "December" = 1, "January" = 1, "February" = 1,
                                     "March" = 2, "April" = 2, "May" = 2,
                                     "June" = 3, "July" = 3, "August" = 3,
                                     "September" = 4, "October" = 4, "November" = 4)})

          Duration <- reactive({switch(input$Duration, 
                                       "less than 4" = 1,
                                       "4 - 6" = 2,
                                       "7 - 9" = 3,
                                       "10 - 12" = 4,
                                       "13 - 15" = 5,
                                       "16 - 20" = 6,
                                       "more than 20" = 7
          )})


          NumberOfPersons <- reactive({switch(input$NumberOfPersons, 
                                              "12" = 12,
                                              "11" = 11,
                                              "10" = 10,
                                              "9" = 9,
                                              "8" = 8,
                                              "7" = 7,
                                              "6" = 6,
                                              "5" = 5,
                                              "4" = 4,
                                              "3" = 3,
                                              "2" = 2,
                                              "1" = 1
          )})

                  travelCBR(Accomodation(), 
                  NumberOfPersons(), 
                  Transportation(), 
                  HolidayType(), 
                  Season(), Duration(), Price())
        })



    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also usually try to avoid the Submit button. Here is an example using `actionButton`. With `eventReactive` you isolate all reactive connections in the expression and only use `input$Update` as a trigger.

Btw, `renderXXX` is a reactive, so you don't have to use `reactive` inside a `renderXXX` expression.

#### ui

```
library(shiny)
#source("travelcbr1.R")

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title.
  titlePanel("TRAVEL RECOMMENDATION"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("HolidayType", "Choose an holiday type:", 
                  choices = c("Bathing", "Active", "Education", "Recreation", "Wandering", "Language", "Skiing", "City")),

      selectInput("Transportation", "Choose a means of Transportation:", 
                  choices = c("Plane", "Train", "Coach", "Car")),

      selectInput("Accomodation", "Choose an Accomodation:", 
                  choices = c("One Star", "Two Stars", "Three Stars", "Four Stars", "Five Stars", "Holiday Flat")),

      selectInput("Duration", "Duration (days):", 
                  choices = c("less than 4", "4 - 6", "7 - 9", "10 - 12", "13 - 15", "16 - 20", "more than 20" )),

      numericInput("Price", "Price:", 500),
      # selectInput("Price", "Price ($):",
      #             choices = c("less than 500", "500 - 1000", "1000 - 1500", "1500 - 2000", "2000 - 2500", "2500 - 3000", "3500 - 4000", "4000 - 4500", "500+" )),

      selectInput("Season", "Season:", 
                  choices = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")),

      selectInput("NumberOfPersons", "Number Of Persons:", choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12 and above")),

      helpText("Click submit button to view your six best destinations"),

      actionButton("Update", "Update")
    ),


    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("view")
      # dataTableOutput("view")
    )
  )
))
```

#### Server

```
library(shiny)

#source("travelcbr1.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  View <- eventReactive(input$Update, {

    Accomodation <- switch(input$Accomodation, 
                                     "Holiday Flat" = 6,
                                     "Five Stars" = 5,
                                     "Four Stars" = 4,
                                     "Three Stars" = 3,
                                     "Two Stars" = 2,
                                     "One Star" = 1)

    Price <- input$Price


    Transportation <- switch(input$Transportation, 
                                       "Plane" = 4,
                                       "Train" = 3,
                                       "Coach" = 2,
                                       "Car" = 1)

    HolidayType <- switch(input$HolidayType, 
                                    "Active" = 8,
                                    "Skiing" = 7,
                                    "Bathing" = 6,
                                    "Wandering" = 5,
                                    "Recreation" = 4,
                                    "City" = 3,
                                    "Language"= 2,
                                    "Education" = 1)

    Season <- switch(input$Season, "December" = 1, "January" = 1, "February" = 1,
                               "March" = 2, "April" = 2, "May" = 2,
                               "June" = 3, "July" = 3, "August" = 3,
                               "September" = 4, "October" = 4, "November" = 4)

    Duration <- switch(input$Duration, 
                                 "less than 4" = 1,
                                 "4 - 6" = 2,
                                 "7 - 9" = 3,
                                 "10 - 12" = 4,
                                 "13 - 15" = 5,
                                 "16 - 20" = 6,
                                 "more than 20" = 7)

    NumberOfPersons <- switch(input$NumberOfPersons, 
                                        "12" = 12,
                                        "11" = 11,
                                        "10" = 10,
                                        "9" = 9,
                                        "8" = 8,
                                        "7" = 7,
                                        "6" = 6,
                                        "5" = 5,
                                        "4" = 4,
                                        "3" = 3,
                                        "2" = 2,
                                        "1" = 1)

    list(Accomodation = Accomodation, 
      NumberOfPersons = NumberOfPersons, 
      Transportation = Transportation, 
      HolidayType = HolidayType, 
      Season = Season, Duration = Duration, Price = Price)

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$view <- renderPrint(View())

})
```

Comment: Thanks. This idea works in that the object in the list function updates, but when I replaced the list function with my function, i.e. travelCBR(Accomodation = Accomodation,
              NumberOfPersons = NumberOfPersons,
              Transportation = Transportation,
              HolidayType = HolidayType,
              Season = Season, Duration = Duration, Price = Price), the output still does not update. Actually, I expect change in the values of the argument should update the result. I also think replacing the list function in the serve code with my function should automatically work.

Comment: Ah, I think I know. Try to define the function without default values for arguments. So, instead of `fun(a = a)` just `fun(a)`

Comment: Thanks. I have defined the function to be without default values for the arguments (i.e.travelCBR(Accomodation, NumberOfPersons,  Transportation,  HolidayType, Season, Duration, Price), but still, the result does not update. When I tried to run the base rcode, by changing the argument values in the function, the result changes. Then I tried to manually change the values of the argument in the function from shiny, the result does not change. Does it mean the base rcode is not reactive? I am so sorry. I am new to Shiny; I found it to be good GUI.

Comment: No, the error must be something else. Can you post the function please? Or a better, a minimal example of a function that does not work as intended?

Comment: Thanks. The function is exactly this: travelCBR(Accomodation, NumberOfPersons, Transportation, HolidayType, Season, Duration, Price). This function is called from shiny server.R. My base R code is deployed to shiny using source("travelcbr1.R"). The whole r code in the travelcbr1.R file is contained in the travelCBR() function. When I ran the base R code at different times by varying the values of the arguments in  travelCBR(), the result also varies as I expect. But when I called travelCBR() in shiny, and vary the argument values using the input shiny console, the result remains static.

Comment: So, if I change the `list(Accomodation ... Price)` part in the server with some function, it is still working. Reactives are also just chunks of code that are executed whenever a reactive variable is changed inside the reactive. The only problem I know of is, when you define the function with a default argument and this argument changes later on, that this change is not incorporated if you call the function without defining the argument (relying on the default).

Comment: Hi, the list(Accomodation ... Price) is reative, but when I change the list(Accomodation ... Price) to travelCBR(Accomodation ... Price) which is the function to display my result, then my result is not updated. Yet, changing argument values in my base r code works. Somehow, I am able to use unlist() to link  reactive list(Accomodation ... Price) to my travelCBR(Accomodation ... Price). Then, my result updates each time I click the action button. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, the list is just the kind of output that I put for the reactive. So, `View()` is one big reactive. The last lines with `list(....)` is the return value. So the reactive `View()` returns all these values as a list. If you replace these last lines with a call to your function, than whatever your function returns will be the return value of `View()`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `actionButton` instead of `submitButton` and isolate the reactivity, with

```
shinyServer(function(input,output) {
   observer({
      if(input$goButton != 0) {
         value$transportation <- <something>
      }
    })
    output$view <- renderTable({
       values$transportation
    })
  }
```

`

Comment: Hi, I have used actionButton instead of submitButton and also if(input$goButton != 0), but still result does not update. What I want is that result should update after changing the input. In other words, I expect a new result after each click on the action button, particularly, after the input has been changed.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you more pointers. Hope it helps